# VSPerf and Azure Cloud Services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, hosting

When I deploy a cloud service to Windows Azure it causes a number of VSPerf.exe instances to start - anything from 1 to 5.

Between them they consume all the CPU and none of the processes ever terminate themselves.

If I remotely connect to the instance and terminate the processes manually they restart on the next request. If the process is terminated during the request then the request succeeds and the page displays and functions as expected.

The only difference between this is a previous deployment is I have since upgraded to .NET 4.5 and therefore upgraded the cloud service to server 2012.

What could be causing this?

#### Update

For every failed start up 2 events are logged:

- `VsPerf Tool Error: Error starting data collection with a dedicated process D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\VSPerf.`
- `.NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.18010 - Loading profiler failed during CoCreateInstance.  Profiler CLSID: '{44a86cad-f7ee-429c-83eb-f3cde3b87b70}'.  HRESULT: 0x80040111.  Process ID (decimal): 1444.  Message ID: [0x2504].`

#### Update 2

The VSPerf issue does not occur after a new instance is created or the machines are reimaged (at least thats a fix (an annoying and time consuming fix) for now).

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I'm seeing the same issue :/

Comment: Afraid not, I have to re-image after every single deploy :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the Azure publish settings in Visual Studio, I'd bet you have enabled profiling on the Advanced tab.

[image: VS Publish Settings]

Comment: Correct! Thanks so much - I'd have never thought to look there. Ironically CPU Sampling "Monitor CPU-bound applications with low overhead" was checked!

Comment: I am also getting this. However CPU sampling should not take up 100% CPU. This is crazy!

Comment: I have this as well, but CPU sampling is useful, and I don't want to remove it.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue, 2 processes of VSPerf.exe burning 100% of CPU on 2nd role instance. IIS becomes unresponsive on that instance. We had the exact same issue 4 months back, disappeared "somehow" when profiling was enabled just when we were debugging this issue with MSFT support (someone inside MSFT knows this issue). But without being able to repro the issue (we only had screenshots) it was dropped.

Since I see it again, 5 minutes back and since Azure SDK 2.0 makes it easy to grab diagnostic logs (unlike the configuration ritual from SDK 1.8), here is something useful for the next folks to make sense off

The core error is `Application  VsPerf Tool Error: Error starting data collection with a dedicated process D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\VSPerf.` with the detailed logs (4 entries) below. Interestingly I had 2 processes of VSPerf.exe burning 100% of CPU and also had 2 log entries ....

```
{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}  Service Control Manager 7011    System  A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the iphlpsvc service.  <Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='Service Control Manager' Guid='{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}' EventSourceName='Service Control Manager'/><EventID Qualifiers='49152'>7011</EventID><Version>0</Version><Level>2</Level><Task>0</Task><Opcode>0</Opcode><Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2013-06-23T17:37:25.557218700Z'/><EventRecordID>1269</EventRecordID><Correlation/><Execution ProcessID='520' ThreadID='1104'/><Channel>System</Channel><Computer>RD00155DA909B8</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data Name='param1'>30000</Data><Data Name='param2'>iphlpsvc</Data></EventData></Event>   WebApp_IN_1 6/23/2013 5:37 PM   2   520 1104
{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}  Service Control Manager 7011    System  A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the Schedule service.  <Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='Service Control Manager' Guid='{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}' EventSourceName='Service Control Manager'/><EventID Qualifiers='49152'>7011</EventID><Version>0</Version><Level>2</Level><Task>0</Task><Opcode>0</Opcode><Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2013-06-23T17:37:56.259560100Z'/><EventRecordID>1270</EventRecordID><Correlation/><Execution ProcessID='520' ThreadID='1104'/><Channel>System</Channel><Computer>RD00155DA909B8</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data Name='param1'>30000</Data><Data Name='param2'>Schedule</Data></EventData></Event>   WebApp_IN_1 6/23/2013 5:37 PM   2   520 1104
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    VSPERF  4100    Application VsPerf Tool Error: Error starting data collection with a dedicated process D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\VSPerf. <Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='VSPERF'/><EventID Qualifiers='57635'>4100</EventID><Level>2</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2013-06-23T17:40:37.000000000Z'/><EventRecordID>266</EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer>RD00xxxxxxxxx</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data>Error starting data collection with a dedicated process D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\VSPerf.</Data></EventData></Event> WebApp_IN_1 6/23/2013 5:40 PM   2   0   0
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    VSPERF  4100    Application VsPerf Tool Error: Error starting data collection with a dedicated process D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\VSPerf. <Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='VSPERF'/><EventID Qualifiers='57635'>4100</EventID><Level>2</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2013-06-23T17:40:41.000000000Z'/><EventRecordID>267</EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer>RD00xxxxxxxxx</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data>Error starting data collection with a dedicated process D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\VSPerf.</Data></EventData></Event> WebApp_IN_1 6/23/2013 5:40 PM   2   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've found to a workaround is to create a startup task

```
<Task commandLine="VSPerf.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background" />
```

where `VSPerf.cmd` is a simple launcher

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted .\VSPerf.ps1
exit /B 0
```

for a PowerShell script which attempts to kill over-active VSPerf instances:

```
function Restart-VSPerf {
    $procs = (
        gwmi -Query "SELECT IDProcess,PercentProcessorTime FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process WHERE Name='vsperf' AND PercentProcessorTime > 25" |
        Foreach-Object { $_pid = $_.IDProcess ; gwmi -Query "SELECT Handle,CommandLine FROM win32_process WHERE Name='vsperf.exe' AND Handle=$_pid" | Select-Object Handle, CommandLine }
    )
    if ($procs) {
        # Get VSPerf path.
        # NB The regex uses conditional matching with an expression, as described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36xybswe.aspx
        # to ensure that a single capturing group gets the contents of quoted arguments and unquoted arguments.
        $regex = [regex] '^(("?)((?(?<=")[^"]*|[^"\s]*))\2(\s+|$))+$'
        $vsperf = $regex.Match($procs[0].CommandLine).Groups[3].Captures[0].Value

        & $vsperf /detach

        # Kill
        $procs | Foreach-Object { Stop-Process -Force -Id $_.Handle }

        # Restart
        Start-Sleep -s 1
        $procs | Foreach-Object {
            $_args = ($regex.Match($_.CommandLine).Groups[3].Captures[1..99] |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value)
            Start-Process $vsperf -ArgumentList "$_args"
        }
    }
}

while (1) {
    Start-Sleep -s 180
    Restart-VSPerf
}
```

It works sometimes but not always. Suggestions for reliability improvements welcome.